# HTTP DOM: request.use? Usage?

Tags: dom, prototypejs, httprequest, scriptaculous

I'm looking at the following code block in javascript:

```
var request = new Request();
if(request.Use()) // What exactly does this do?
{
    // ...do stuff
}
else
{
   // no ajax support?
}
```

I've never seen anyone invoke the request.Use() method.

My Question:

> - What exactly does request.Use()    check?
>
>   - Does it in fact check for AJAX    support?
>   - Can anyone redirect me to an online API reference?

**EDIT:** Thanks for the helpful feedback.
I see both prototype and scriptaculous includes.

> Has anyone seen request.Use() in
>   *either* **prototype** or **scriptaculous**?

Comment: Expanding on SLaks' comment: That's not standard JavaScript or DOM, so apparently you're using a library of some sort. That doesn't immediately look like jQuery, Prototype, or Closure, so...do you know what library it is?

Answer (score 1):

No, I've never seen `Request.Use` in Prototype or script.aculo.us. (I know Prototype very well and it's definitely not that. Scripty [as it's sometimes known] I know less well but I'm pretty sure that's not scripty, either. [*Edit* It's not, just did a quick search through the scripty source.])

You can find [Prototype docs here](http://prototypejs.org/api) (old docs) and [here](http://api.prototypejs.org) (new docs, not entirely complete) and [scripty docs here](http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/).

If the page is using Prototype, search (case sensitive) for the strings `function Request`, `Request =`, and `Request:` in the source of the page itself and any JavaScript files it refrences to see if someone's defined a wrapper, which it seems likely they have. (If you can use regex to allow unlimited whitespace around those operators, all the better.)